# How to make NextJS show Eslint issues in the console?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

I'm wondering if there's a way in next js to show the eslint issues in either the console or the server after running the development server.
I was able to successfully add custom eslint rules to my next project but i want to make it as strict as posible breaking the dev server and showing the eslint issues when found.

I want to achieve what Create React App does, but in CRA this was somehow built-in. With next this is not the case because the application still runs even after eslint issues were found.